# How micro processor is controlled..?

Tags: microprocessors

How micro processor is controlled? For example, after receiving instructions from memory, the instruction decoder decodes the instruction(???), and the decoded instruction is executed in ALU. How all this happen in a sequence?

Comment: There must be a scheduler/scheduling unit that can access the units you mention, maybe a synchronizing signal too.

Comment: This isn't particularly clear.  A microprocessor is just a sophisticated electronic circuit; that circuit is designed to do all of this automatically.  I suggest reading e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline.

Comment: Microprocessors are driven by a *clock.*  Each time the clock "ticks," the next thing happens in the microprocessor, whatever that is.  The clock in the computer I'm typing this on "ticks" about 3 billion times per second.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for the answer. Could you pls provide the detailed expn of the same with internal behaviour?

Comment: That would take half a book to write. :)  Why don't you pick up a good book on microprocessor fundamentals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a high level, when the microprocessor is given electricity, it sets the [program counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter) to a predefined address in memory where it expects the sequence of program instructions to start. Each instruction tells the microprocessor to do one or more things, such as read/write memory, do math, or change the value of the program counter.

The ALU is the [Arithmetic Logic Unit](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Microprocessor_Design/ALU), which just does the math bits.